# [ASP.NET-MVC]How can I create and edit data within a same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have 2 database the First one is **Events** and the second **EventParticipants**
So once the EventParticipants had added a new data into the database, I wanted to update the current participants amount within the **Events** Database. I tried to put 2 Controller that shared the same name which is **Join** but one of it is using `[HttpPost]` and the other one is using `[HttpPut]` but is won't work so I tried to combine them together but still nothing had changed in the **Events** database.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Join([Bind(Include = "DateAdded,IC,EventsId")] EventParticipants eventParticipants, [Bind(Include = "Current_Participant")] Events events)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.EventParticipants.Add(eventParticipants);
                db.Entry(events).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(eventParticipants);
        }
```

This is the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Join", "JoinEvent", FormMethod.Post, new { Model }))
{
    DBContext db = new DBContext();

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EventsId)

    <input name="DateAdded" type="hidden" value="@DateTime.Now">
    <input name="IC" type="hidden" value="@Session["IC"]">
    <input name="EventsId" type="hidden" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EventsId)">

            var plus = Model.Current_Participant + 10;
    <input name="Current_Participant" type="text" value="@plus" />

    <input type="submit" value="Join Now" class="btn btn-default" />

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this, you can use 2 dbcontext pointing to 2 databases,

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Join([Bind(Include = "DateAdded,IC,EventsId")] EventParticipants eventParticipants, [Bind(Include = "Current_Participant")] Events events)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.EventParticipants.Add(eventParticipants);
                db.Entry(events).State = EntityState.Modified;//this should be insert EventParticipants
                db.SaveChanges();

                dbWithEventsContext.Events.Add(events); //separate dbcontext pointing to Events db
                dbWithEventsContext.Entry(events).State = EntityState.Modified;
                dbWithEventsContext.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(eventParticipants);
        }
```

Comment: It still can't work , I just want to increase the value of the **Current_Participant** by 1 when a new **Event_Participant** data is created, So I changed on using a **EventsVM** and the error message return is like this ``Cannot convert from ViewModel.EventsVM to Model.Events``

Comment: Instead of changed using a view model, you can do with Events entity. Or map your view model to event entity. ViewModel cannot be saved in database with Entityframework